# Sort List by localization

Tags: c#, list, generics, sorting, unicode

I need to sort a `List<string>` which contains Japanese alphabet.
How could I do this in C#?

Comment: I can't promise this, but I think if you sort it with `Compare` given the right CultureInfo it should work out of the box...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an overload `List<T>.Sort(IComparer<T> comparer)`. You can pass a culture specific comparer to the sort method. The following code compares using the Japanese culture settings:

```
myList.Sort(StringComparer.Create(new CultureInfo("ja-JP"), true));
```

In this case I passed `true` as the argument to indicate that the comparison must be case insensitive. The `StringComparer` has a couple of static properties and methods to create a suitable comparer:

```
StringComparer.CurrentCulture;
StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase;
StringComparer.Create(CultureInfo culture, bool ignoreCase);
etc.
```

You can find more information [on this msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.aspx).

Comment: Japanese has no case but has three distinct word ordering conventions.  One is based on pronunciation, one based on a poem, one based on radicals (the parts that make up a character).  That's where I peter out.

Comment: I am going to sort Kana List {Hiragana} So it will be more simple

Comment: I found that when using SortedList I can do this easly

Answer (score 2):

I use:

```
Array.Sort(myArray, StringComparer.Ordinal);
```

It will sort the array by Ascii value, so you'll get hiragana, katakana, and then kanji.