# Sorting Japanese text by Katakana in C#

Tags: c#, sorting, unicode, cjk

Is it possible to sort a list of Japanese strings by their Katakana?

Comment: possible duplicate of [sort List By localization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544955/sort-list-by-localization)

Comment: My knowledge of Japanese can hardly tell the difference, but I believe that that discusses general ASCII based sorting. How do I specifically sort them according to Katakana?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895527/can-sorting-japanese-kanji-words-be-done-programatically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure you can. If you use CultureInfo, you can make it so it doesn't bother looking for upper/lower-case.

```
// Create CultureInfo
System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ja-JP");
//Create the StringComparer
StringComparer cmp = StringComparer.Create(ci, true);

// Sort your array of string
Array.Sort(myArray, cmp);
```

You can extend the functionality of the sort to not distinguish between Hiragana and Katakana if you like by doing this:

```
//Create CultureInfo
System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ja-JP");
// Set it so it ignores the kana type
CultureInfoCompare cmp =
new CultureInfoCompare(ci, System.Globalization.CompareOptions.IgnoreKanaType);
    
//Sort it
Array.Sort(myArray, cmp);
```

頑張ってください！

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sure you can sort katakana strings by their constituent characters. But this will only work if you are only interested in a subset of the Japanese language. In general Japanese strings are made up of hiragana, katakana and kanji.

If you want basic Japanese language sorting, I would use [kakasi](http://kakasi.namazu.org/) to convert kanji to hiragana and then decide how you want to order hiragana and katakana; personally I would be tempted to do あ,　ア,　い,　イ,　う,　ウ, etc.

Comment: Is it possible to do the entire sorting process using some existing library, preferably in C#?

Comment: The problem is that you can't really trust Kakasi (or similar) to convert Kanji into Kana reliably.  If there will be fields holding, f.e. Names, etc. in Kanji, then there should be a matching field where the user inputs the Kana version as well.